# how to validate Jquery plugin url without http or https?

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I want validate url without `http` or `https`.
I'm using JQuery something like:

```
$("#add_users_form").validate({
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            'user_detail[website]': {
                url: true
            },
  }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

@anand, you need to add custom validation method for that, kindly use the below script

```
// add custom validation method 
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkurl", function(value, element) {                                       
    return /^(www\.)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+$/.test(value);
    }, "Please enter a valid URL."
);


 // connect it to a css class
  jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
        checkurl : { checkurl : true }    
 });


'website[url]': {
        checkurl: true
}
```

Comment: I'm using jquery validate plugin, I already tried these code but not solve my problem.

Comment: I think you are new in it. do you know how to apply this?